# What should the plenum temperature be on a modern furnace

Tags: furnace, central-heating

I had a tech out to review my furnace that's not keeping up - a Trane XV80. They poked around, and saw that the plenum temperature is 95F. They then told me that it should be around 140F, which is clearly, substantially more. The thing that confused me is that in the same breath, he said that the temp delta between the return and the plenum should be 20-30F, which would mean a return temp of 110-120, which is impossible.

So - which is it? And what causes a low plenum temp / how can it be remedied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look on the furnace data sticker. Every furnace since at least the 1980s will list the delta on the name plate. It will be a little different for each furnace but will always be a range such as 30-60 degrees. Measure the supply air temperature and subtract the return air temperature. This is basic furnace commissioning 101. Too cold and you risk condensation and rust. To hot and you risk cracking the heat exchanger and damaging other components. A low delta T is typically caused by low gas pressure but there are many other reasons it could be. I always do a combustion analysis when starting up a new furnace. That will tell if the burners are firing properly but is beyond what a home owner could do.

Answer (score 0):

The proper delta T for a heat pump is 20-30*F.  For a forced air fossil fuel furnace I would expect to see 35-70*. If the return air was 50* you could easily have a plenum temp of 95* and if you had really good air flow across the exchanger, the return could be 60* and still have that discharge temp.  As to a remedy there are simply too many factors involved to address through correspondence.   In a nut shell the furnace has to put-out more Bu's than the floor, walls and ceiling loose for any given period.

Comment: This is a gas furnace, and the intake air was at 75, so he quoted me the wrong delta T. They want to do a combustion analysis (and charge for it, of course). Would that be the a reasonable next step, or am I getting fleeced?

Comment: No it is not the next reasonable step.  Something is seriously wrong.  Maybe a weak hi-limit, or flame sensor.  I don't think you are holding a consistent fire.  The furnace must be cycling off before reaching room temperature. I recommend consulting another service outlet.  Your service man is clearly out of his league.